# Swift: SetValue to NSDictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, key-value-coding

I have try to set the array value to array of dictionary key.
 here is my code

this is my Time Slots array Initialization:

```
 arrmTimeSlots = [
            ["time": "6am", "action": []],
            ["time": "7am", "action":  []],
            ["time": "8am", "action":  []],
            ["time": "9am", "action":  []],
            ["time": "10am", "action":  []],
            ["time": "11am", "action":  []],
            ["time": "12pm", "action":  []],
            ["time": "1pm", "action":  []],
            ["time": "2pm", "action":  []],
            ["time": "3pm", "action":  []],
            ["time": "4pm", "action":  []],
            ["time": "5pm", "action":  []],
            ["time": "6pm", "action":  []],
            ["time": "7pm", "action":  []],
            ["time": "8pm", "action":  []],
            ["time": "9pm", "action":  []],
            ["time": "10pm", "action":  []]
        ];
```

I was show the value of 'time' key on tableview initially. When user select day from calendar I was fetching data from database respective to the selected day. the data is in Dictionary format as:

```
{     
   "Description" = "this is discription";
   "End_time" = 201601240645;
   "Location" = "xyz";
   "Rec_uid" = "r576thg8ed-698a-4a71-87e5-366bec44638a";
   "Satrt_time" = 201601240645;
   "Title" = "hrhrcffu";
   "uid" = "c39b2987-5d19-4178-8591-c052b5205ad5";
 }
```

so I want to add this dictionary in ArrmTimeSlots array for "action" key.
Here is my code to add the dictionary in array:

```
 for scheduleDay in arrmTimeSlots
   {                  
     let day = scheduleDay as! NSDictionary

     let timeOnSlots = day["time"] as! String

     let action = day["action"] as! NSArray

     print("time \(timeOnSlots)  action \(action)")

      if(timeOnSlots == concatTimeslotTime) // here compare time if true set array to action key
         {
            day.setValue(array, forKey: "action")
         }
 }
```

but, My app is crash and get the error on 'd.setValue(array, forKey: "action")' this line :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<_TtGCSs29_NativeDictionaryStorageOwnerSSCSo8NSObject_ 0x1566dbc0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key action.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x240dc0d7 0x32778c77 0x240dbde5 0x24d71c95 0x1ea1c4 0x1e7888 0x1e57f4 0x1e5974 0x107c2b 0xfc95d 0x27d36dd9 0x2793f495 0x2793f197 0x278bb4c9 0x278bb4c9 0x2776dee3 0x277677f1 0x2773d9b5 0x279b40ff 0x2773c3b7 0x240a200f 0x240a1423 0x2409faa1 0x23feb6d1 0x23feb4e3 0x2b9581a9 0x2779d445 0x17ffd8 0x32d46aaf)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Please Suggest me solution for this.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: you have to use `setObject` instead of `setValue`

Comment: Where is `d` defined?

Comment: @SandyChapman see the my edited question. it's 'day'.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use Foundation collection types (`NSArray`, `NSDictionary`) rather than Swift native types?

Comment: By the way, you have to use a `NSMutableDictionary` otherwise you won't be able to change value (of course using `setObject`, not `setValue`). Also note that `day["action"] = array` will also work with `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: @Sulthan if i use NSMutableDictionary then my app is crash. and gives error : Could not cast value of type 'Swift._NativeDictionaryStorageOwner<Swift.String, NSObject>' (0x426c240) to 'NSMutableDictionary' (0x3311dd04).

Comment: @Sulthan so how can i solve this?

Comment: @PallaviNikumbh You are not using a `NSMutableDictionary`. Just casting a variable of type `NSDictionary` to `NSMutableDictionary` doesn't make it mutable. Casting is just a way to cheat the compiler to think it's mutable.

Comment: @Sulthan I already do that, means I was cast the NSDictionary to NSMutableDictionary but it gives me error of swift_native dictionary

Comment: @Sulthan is right, you need to declare arrmTimeSlots as an array of NSMutableDictionary, not NSDictionary

Comment: @Sulthan I am try to do that but it gives error :(

Comment: Can please suggest me using code. I will better for me to understand that where is I am wrong. :)

Comment: The source of your problem lies earlier in your code, so it would be best if you post some code of how and what items you add to `arrmTimeSlots`.

Comment: Please show us the declaration of `arrmTimeSlots` and we can help you improve your code.

Comment: @Sulthan see the edited question.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to overwrite the array item with a modified object. You can user `enumerate()` to get and index and object in each iteration at the same time.

Secondly, when declaring the `day` variable, you need to use `var` instead of `let` so you can modify it.

Here is a sample code:

```
for (i, scheduleDay) in arrmTimeSlots.enumerate()
{
    var day = scheduleDay

    let timeOnSlots = day["time"]

    let action = day["action"]

    print("time \(timeOnSlots)  action \(action)")

    if(timeOnSlots == concatTimeslotTime) // here compare time if true set array to action key
    {
        day["action"] = array
        arrmTimeSlots[i] = day
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your repeat loop is very inefficient because all items are evaluated even if the first item already matches the time.

At first glance `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` seem to be more convenient because you don't have to take care of the type but that's a false conclusion.

This is a native Swift solution replacing your entire repeat loop.
If gets the index of the array using the `indexOf` function, assigns the array if necessary and updates the item in the `arrmTimeSlots` array.

The only disadvantage is you have to assign child items back to parent items due to the value type semantics of Swift collection types

```
if let indexOfTimeOnSlots = arrmTimeSlots.indexOf( { $0["time"] as! String == concatTimeslotTime }) {
  var item = arrmTimeSlots[indexOfTimeOnSlots]
  item["action"] = array
  arrmTimeSlots[indexOfTimeOnSlots] = item
}
```

I recommend to use a custom `struct` rather than a dictionary for the `arrmTimeSlots` items. It can avoid more type casting yet.

Comment: very cool solution. not if there are multiple occurrences of the same time value, but it should be just right in this case.

Comment: The sample array in the question has unique time entries.

Comment: yeah, that's why in this case it's perfect

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you have declared it as a NSDictionary, so make it NSMutableDictionary and it will work. :)